# ProgressDialog crash when I change to landscape OnFocusChangeListener

Tags: progressdialog

I have inside a Fragment an event OnfocuChangeListener for a EditText. I programmed that when it has no focus, search on a remote DB to check if the user exist. Inside the listener I create the ProgressDialog. If I have the focus in the EditText and I change to landscape, it crash when .dismiss() the ProgressDialog. Any idea?

```
txtUsuario.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                if (!hasFocus) {

                    pDialog.setMessage("Comprobando si existe usuario..., espere.");
                    pDialog.show();

                    strq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_user, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                String responseString = mainObject.getString("success");

                                //SI SE REALIZÓ LA GRABACIÓN
                                if (responseString.equals("1")) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ya existe ese usuario, elija otro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    txtUsuario.setText("");
                                    txtUsuario.requestFocus();
                                } else {
                                    // **** HERE CRASH ****
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            //pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error del servidor: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
                            parametros.put("usuario", txtUsuario.getText().toString());
                            return parametros;
                        }
                    };
                    rqt.add(strq);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found muself a solution. I created a boolean=false. And onPause I change the that value to true and DO NOTHING onFocusChangeListener if the value is true.

The only way I could find.